# C# Video concatenation using FFMpegConverter

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I need to implement video concatenation in my ASP.NET Web API. I could successfully concatenate some sample videos downloaded from internet using 'FFMpegConverter' Nuget Package . But when I tried concatenating files captured from my mobile and tried opening it, I got the following error. 
[image]

Below is the code snippet I'm using:

```
var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
ffMpeg.ConcatMedia(_fileNames, videoRootPath.mp4, 
                   NReco.VideoConverter.Format.mp4, set);
```

These are the Property screenshots of both the mp4 files.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got correct output by making the following changes to the code

```
  var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
                NReco.VideoConverter.ConcatSettings set = new NReco.VideoConverter.ConcatSettings();
                ffMpeg.ConcatMedia(_fileNames, videoRootPath + tobename + ".mp4", NReco.VideoConverter.Format.mp4, set);
```

NReco.VideoConverter.ConcatSettings had to be initialised with default values. This should have been the fourth parameter to "ffMpeg.Concatmedia" method.

Comment: @b_in_U can you please let me know using FFMpegConverter() upload video which default size is user for upload video time that which limit it's use?